# Style WP plugin output : columns and font size

Tags: php, wordpress

I use the "simple posts list" - wordpress plugin which outputs all posts as a long list - how can you style the output, say in 4 columns, and determine font size (as far as I know it's not possible in php)?
Looks not too difficult, but I have no knowledge of php...so please tell me where to change what...

```
    function posts_list () {
    $output='<ul>';
    $posts = get_posts('numberposts=-1');
    foreach($posts as $post){
        $permalink = get_permalink( $post->ID );
        $output.= '<li>' . '<a href="' . $permalink . '">' . $post->post_title     .         '</a></li>';
    }
    $output.='</ul>';
    return $output;
}

function pages_list () {
    $output='<ul>';
    $pages = get_pages();
    foreach($pages as $page){
        $permalink = get_permalink( $page->ID );
        $output.= '<li>' . '<a href="' . $permalink . '">' . $page->post_title .     '</a></li>';
    }
    $output.='</ul>';
    return $output;
}

add_shortcode('posts','posts_list');
add_shortcode('pages','pages_list');

?>
```

Many thanks!
Michael

Comment: You won't be able to do this with a pure PHP solution and have it render as you intend across different devices. You'll need a jQuery/JavaScript solution.The only PHP changes you'll need are to add a `class` to the `<ul>` tags, then use `wp_enqueue_script()` to add code like [this](http://codepen.io/jawittdesigns/pen/zhCrv)

Answer (score 0):

A simple CSS only approach could be to float your list elements left and give them a width of 25% total.  Maybe add some padding so they aren't touching.  So a width of 23% and left and right padding of 1% for a total of 25%.

```
ul{list-style-type: none;} 
li{float: left; width: 23%; padding: 0 1%;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QRU2S/2/)

Comment: this certainly would work, however, it also would change all other lists across the website. Is there any solution to apply this to just one single page where the list output by this plugin is shown?